# Installing private npm packages with an authentication key

Tags: npm, artifactory

I'm using Artifactory to pull npm packages. One of the packages that I use is stored privately and in order to access it the publisher gave me an authentication token.

I was asked to add `//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=<private_token>` to `.npmrc`, however my environment use Artifactory as a proxy for the public npm registry. How can I configure an authentication token geared specifically for the package?

Answer (score 0):

You can use virtual repo concept of artifactory. You can upload the custom packages into your local repo and a common repo that will get the packages from the npm

Comment: Thank you. It means that for each new version I'll have to manually upload the package again, right? Can you point me to documentation that describe the process.

Comment: You can have an automation as well for uploading custom package to let's say repo name local where all custom packages will be uploaded. Let me search for the documentation